# Boot errors Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, boot-repair, firmware

For a couple of weeks now when booting I get multiple errors. Ubuntu still launches and I don't see any problems, but of course I am worried.  I used boot-repair, which seems to have reduced the number of errors but not eliminated all of them. I sent the output of journalctl -b to a file but I don't see how to attach it to this question.  I hesitate to paste the entire contents here as it is over 4000 lines.

```
Aug 03 09:32:10 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge

Aug 03 09:32:10 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xdda96000-0xdda96fff flags 0x200] vs dda96000 4000

Aug 03 09:32:26 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: ACPI BIOS 

Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20210730/dsopcode-133)
Aug 03 09:32:10 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: tpm_crb: probe of MSFT0101:00 failed with error -16
Aug 03 09:32:10 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
Aug 03 09:32:10 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
Aug 03 09:32:26 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20210730/dsopcode-133)
Aug 03 09:32:26 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \HWMC due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
Aug 03 09:32:26 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
Aug 03 09:32:26 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20210730/dsopcode-133)
Aug 03 09:32:26 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \HWMC due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
Aug 03 09:32:26 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
Aug 03 09:32:26 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20210730/dsopcode-133)
Aug 03 09:32:26 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \HWMC due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
Aug 03 09:32:26 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)
Aug 03 09:32:57 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: server[1260]: segfault at 1a0 ip 00007f8f6b194b00 sp 00007f8f66e7ec28 error 4 in libudev.so.1.6.9[7f8f6b191000+1d000]
Aug 03 09:33:07 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: server[1434]: segfault at 1a0 ip 00007fc83f984b00 sp 00007fc83b66ec28 error 4 in libudev.so.1.6.9[7fc83f981000+1d000]
Aug 03 09:33:07 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: server[1466]: segfault at 1a0 ip 00007f8e008ccb00 sp 00007f8dfc5b6c28 error 4 in libudev.so.1.6.9[7f8e008c9000+1d000]
Aug 03 09:33:08 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: server[1493]: segfault at 1a0 ip 00007fe24ddb4b00 sp 00007fe249a9ec28 error 4 in libudev.so.1.6.9[7fe24ddb1000+1d000]
Aug 03 09:33:09 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: server[1519]: segfault at 1a0 ip 00007f00b79c4b00 sp 00007f00b36aec28 error 4 in libudev.so.1.6.9[7f00b79c1000+1d000]
Aug 03 09:33:09 dave-HP-All-in-One-24-f0xx kernel: server[1544]: segfault at 1a0 ip 00007f25a9c2cb00 sp 00007f25a5916c28 error 4 in libudev.so.1.6.9[7f25a9c29000+1d000]
```

Answer (score 1):

The notices about ACPI started happening a long time ago but kernel 5.13 had a few more of these notices.

What is going on is that your BIOS hands out information to the kernel but the kernel does not understand what it is receiving. A lot of times this is a BIOS with faulty software and our newer kernels show a message during boot time.

There are two possible ways to fix this:

- find a newer BIOS that does give out correct information.
- update to a newer kernel

Often these two go hand in hand: a newer kernel has improvements better supporting a BIOS. A newer BIOS will have bugfixes that the newer kernel processes better.

It is possible to not show these notices but it would disable everything ACPI related. But most of us ignore them :)

> I  sent the output of journalctl -b to a file but I don't see how to attach it to this question. I hesitate to paste the entire contents here as it is over 4000 lines.

If you do want to post that only cherry pick the important lines. 10 lines is  more than enough.

---

```
segfault at 1a0 ip 00007f8f6b194b00 sp 00007f8f66e7ec28 error 4 in libudev.so.1.6.9
```

is a bit more serious.  Do you mix versions? If so different libraries linking different versions of `libudev` will lead to a segfault.  If not a bug report is needed.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure how much is needed.

Comment: I only have Ubuntu 20.04 as far as I know.  I certainly did not intend to mix versions.